# Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am fetching news feeds from different sources & adding to DB but I get below exception

> Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake.
>       at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/home/vikas/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:210:16)
>       at Protocol._enqueue (/home/vikas/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:139:13)
>       at Protocol.handshake (/home/vikas/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
>       at Connection.connect (/home/vikas/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
>       at storeNewsFeedsInDB (/home/vikas/NodeJS Practice/fetchNews.js:42:7)
>       at newsapi.v2.everything.then.response (/home/vikas/NodeJS Practice/fetchNews.js:33:9)
>       at tryCatcher (/home/vikas/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/vikas/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/home/vikas/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/vikas/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (/home/vikas/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
>       at Async._drainQueue (/home/vikas/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
>       at Async._drainQueues (/home/vikas/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/home/vikas/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:637:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:610:5)

Below is my code

```
const NewsAPI = require('newsapi');
const newsapi = new NewsAPI('*****************************');

var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "****",
  user: "****",
  password: "****",
  database: "****"
});

var channels = ['bbc-news', 'the-verge', 'reuters', 'cnbc', 'bloomberg', 'economist', 'nytimes'];
var topics = ['technology', 'business', 'finance', 'tech', 'economics', 'company'];

for (var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < topics.length; j++) {
    newsapi.v2.everything({
      q: topics[j],
      // q: 'technology',
      sources: channels[i],
      // sources: 'bloomberg',
      // domains: 'bbc.co.uk, techcrunch.com',
      from: '2018-03-14',
      to: '2018-03-14',
      language: 'en',
      sortBy: 'relevancy',
      pageSize:100,
      page: 1
    }).then(response => {
      // console.log(response);
      for (var i = 0; i < response.articles.length; i++) {
        // console.log(response.articles[i].title);
        storeNewsFeedsInDB(response.articles[i].title, 
                            response.articles[i].description, 
                              response.articles[i].url);
      }
    });
  }
}

function storeNewsFeedsInDB(title, description, url) {
  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");

    //Insert a record in the "newsfeeds" table:
    var sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO newsfeeds (`title`, `description`, `url`) VALUES ('" 
                + title.replace(/'/g, "\\'") + "', '" + description.replace(/'/g, "\\'") + "', '" + url + "')";
                console.log(sql);
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 record inserted");
    });
  });
}
```

New to Nodejs & Mysql, please help me.

Answer (score 6):

You are calling `storeNewsFeedsInDB` from inside a (nested) loop, and each time it's accessed you call `con.connect`, that's why you get that "enqueued handshake" error. A look at [one of `mysql` npm package test suites](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/49939c525725e13067356faf73ec557d6c526e13/test/unit/connection/test-double-connect.js) can be revealing, as the error is thrown as soon as two successive `con.connect`calls are made.

You should be good by just removing that `con.connect` call from your code, as any `query` call established the connection implicitly, [as the docs say](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#establishing-connections).

Comment: Hey, even I use node-MySQL and connect to the express js server. I get the same error if I reload the page and enter the details again. Can you suggest me what to do?